# Cucumber get name of test runner class

Tags: java, class, cucumber, runner

I'm trying to get the name of the current executing runner class, e.g. for:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features={"Features"},
glue={"src.stepdefinition"},
monochrome=false
)
public class HelloWorld {
}
```

I need to have the class name "HelloWorld" available in my java code. Does anybody know how to get it?
I've already tried this: http://ramblingsofaswtester.com/2013/04/15/cucumber-test-name-and-tags-on-feature/ and this definitly goes to right direction, but it doesn't contains the runner class name.

EDIT: Because I use Maven I can access the

```
System.getProperty("test")
```

which contains the package name with class name.

Comment: Hi, were you able to retrieve the Runner class name at run time?